# move_uploaded_file() using temporary hosting account domain

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, cpanel

I'm trying to upload an image using PHP using the function `move_uploaded_file()`.

**PHP**

```
// Get image variables
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$path = "images/products/large/";
$image_hash = "ty1bi"; // This would be generated

//I have also tried this: $path = "home/the_user/public_html/images/products/large/";
//$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is equal to home/root_user/public_html/

// Upload image
if(!move_uploaded_file($file, $path . $image_hash . ".jpg")) {      
  header("location:admin/add.php?e=1");
  exit;
}
```

At the moment, I'm getting:

*Warning: move_uploaded_file(home/root_user/public_html/images/products/large/ty1bi.jpg)
[function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in
/home/root_user/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 63*

*Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move
'/tmp/phpJSKsYA' to 'home/root_user/public_html/images/products/large/ty1bi.jpg'
in /home/root_user/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 63*

The hosting account was set up in WHM and I'm accessing the site via the `/~the_user/` directory.  So the site name would be either the main/root host domain name or the server IP address, followed by `/~the_user`.

Because the error is showing the `/root_user` which would be the username of the WHM host, I don't think it is able to access the `/~the_user`.  I have tried changing the document root in `$path` so it starts from `home/` and includes `/the_user` but I'm also having no luck.

Is there a way to do this or will I have to use/test this on a domain name?

**UPDATE**

Because the document root was under the root username, the problem that was occurring was the correct build of the absolute path.  I was sort of in the right direction by building the path, but this was absolute due to the missing slash at the beginning of the path string.

This line of code helped fixed the issue:

`$path = "/home/the_user/public_html/images/products/large/";`

Comment: are you sure there's `images/products/larger/...` UNDER the directory where this script is executing?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely sure.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning this script is fired in `/includes/functions.php` but this shouldn't matter if I'm referencing the document root?

Comment: Have you checked `$_FILES['image']['error']` to verify that the file was successfully uploaded?

Comment: makes me wonder about the fact that the errors is `'home/...` without a leading `/`. could be a security setting somewhere stripping that off, making PHP think it should be putting the file into a subdir called `home/...` under your CWD.

Comment: @DaveRandom `$_FILES['image']['error']` returns 0

Comment: @MarcB - which part are you talking about, what `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is returning?

Comment: Sounds to me like the server paths and permissions are not configured correctly in that case. I would contact the hosting provider about the issue.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the configuration - I think the reason is because it's being viewed on the temp domain that cPanel has set up (this might be Apache). The fact the domain is `http://www.mydomain.com/~the_user/` and the cPanel username of `mydomain.com` is `root_user`, it's trying to access the files of `root_user` and NOT `the_user`.

Comment: @Titanium": in that case, use an absolute path: `$target = '/home/the_user/etc..`, and not the relative path you're building.

Comment: @MarcB - I tried that, as stated on line 6.  No luck.

Comment: no. you haven't. notice the leading `/`. without the leading /, you're just building a RELATIVE path.

Comment: Ah okay, how does PHP know you're using an absolute path anyway?

Comment: You're right @MarcB - the leading `/` was the issue.  Put it as an answer and I'll accept! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Titanium: any path which doesn't start with a `/` is considered relative, including things like `./` and `../`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes me wonder about the fact that the errors is 'home/... without a leading /. could be a security setting somewhere stripping that off, making PHP think it should be putting the file into a subdir called home/... under your CWD.

Try

```
/home/.....
^---
```

instead

Comment: Just out of interest, what is CWD?

Comment: It stands for "current working directory" ... you muppet.